# Magento 2 - How to add short_description to cart item?

Tags: magento2, cart-items

On the `/checkout/cart` page I like to add the short description attribute to the cart items. But if I look in `$item->getProduct()->getShortDescription()` I get an empty string, also `$item->getProduct()->hasShortDescription()` returns `false`.

I also read somewhere that the `short_description` attribute isn't loaded automatically and need to add this piece of xml to M2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="short_description"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

But I am unsure of where to add this exactly or that I even need this. So can somebody help me out?

Comment: This link should help you out. 
[link] http://webkul.com/blog/add-product-information-checkout-cart-in-magento2/

Let us know if that doesnt help.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can add the custom attribute to `catalog_attributes.xml` under `etc` folder.

For example:

*app/code/Company/Catalog/etc/catalog_attributes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="short_description"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Now, we can get `$item->getProduct()->getShortDescription()`.

See more here: `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/catalog_attributes.xml`

Comment: Khoa Thank you, it's so easy but I couldn't get it to work :)

Comment: Running on version 2.1.9  this method does not work, added catalog_attributes.xml to app/code/custom/catalog/etc and updated default.phtml under Custom theme Magento_Checkout/templates/car/item/default.phtml
What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why isn't it possible to overwrite this file in custom theme?  
Edit: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223451/how-to-override-magento-directory-module-etc-xml-file

Comment: Thanks, it's working :D

Answer (score 2):

Full solution as provided by @Khoa TruongDinh

Create a custom module in app/code/vendor/ModuleName/.

app/code/vendor/ModuleName/etc/catalog_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="short_description"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

app/code/vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/vendor/ModuleName/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'vendor_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now we can add in any phtml where it is needed.
echo $product->getShortDescription()

Run magento commands:

php bin/magento module:enable vendor_ModuleName

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

Check frontend