# How to override Magento directory module /etc XML file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, xml

I am trying to override the ZIP code validation xml file in Magento's Directory module. I'm doing this because I want to enforce a space in UK postcodes. The path of the file I'm attempting to override is:

```
/vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/zip_codes.xml
```

I'm attempting to override this by creating a file in my theme with the same name:

```
/app/design/frontend/[Company]/[Theme]/Magento_Directory/etc/zip_codes.xml
```

This hasn't had the desired effect, I presume I'm missing a key step but I've not been able to figure out what else is required. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code that you have to try override zipcode xml

Comment: I have simply tried cloning the file from and to the locations specified, and changing a single word to check to see if the new version is being used. This is not the case, so I believe the problem is the file location or my method, rather than a code issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot **overwrite** an existing XML file from the `etc` directory. What you are trying to do is working for files in the `view` directory only.

What you can do is **extend** an existing XML file with your own module which will be loaded after the `Magento_Directory` module (controlled by the `<sequence>` tag in the module.xml). This module can have a `etc/zip_codes.xml` file too. Don't copy all of the original file, just the header and the footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Directory:etc/zip_codes.xsd">
</config>
```

So let's assume you want to change the zip range for Australia (AU) which is as follows by default:

```
<zip countryCode="AU">
    <codes>
        <code id="pattern_1" active="true" example="1234">^[0-9]{4}$</code>
    </codes>
</zip>
```

You can add a second range in your own module:

```
<zip countryCode="AU">
    <codes>
        <code id="pattern_2" active="true" example="12345">^[0-9]{5}$</code>
    </codes>
</zip>
```

Or disable an existing pattern:

```
<zip countryCode="AU">
    <codes>
        <code id="pattern_1" active="false" />
    </codes>
</zip>
```

Or change an existing entry:

```
<zip countryCode="AU">
    <codes>
        <code id="pattern_1" active="true" example="12345">^[0-9]{5}$</code>
    </codes>
</zip>
```

You can access an existing entry by using the same main identifier `id`.

For your case the zip_codes.xml will probably look as follows (`+` removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Directory:etc/zip_codes.xsd">
    <zip countryCode="GB">
        <codes>
            <code id="pattern_1" active="true" example="AB12 3CD">^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}$</code>
            <code id="pattern_2" active="true" example="A1B 2CD">^[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}\s[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}$</code>
            <code id="pattern_3" active="true" example="AB1 2CD">^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}\s[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}$</code>
            <code id="pattern_4" active="true" example="AB1C 2DF">^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}\s[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}$</code>
            <code id="pattern_5" active="true" example="A12 3BC">^[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}$</code>
            <code id="pattern_6" active="true" example="A1 2BC">^[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}\s[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}$</code>
        </codes>
    </zip>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andreas, you've definitely explained well where I went wrong, and what should be done. After following this methodology, which I also found explained [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_zip.html). I ran in to the issue described [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4131) - which still seems to be a problem in Magento 2.1.12. I've used a workaround described in this issue which has resolved my problem.