# Magento 2.3 How to override the custom theme's etc/layouts.xml file in recommended way?

Tags: php, layout, xml, magento2.3.1

There is, in a theme that I bought a layout.xml file that is used in the backoffice to hydrat a select element (that allows you to switch between 5 layouts).

`app/code/CompanyTheme/LayoutSwitcher/etc/layouts.xml`

this file contains

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:CompanyTheme_LayoutSwitcher:etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="header_layout_1" label="Header Layout 1" type="header" />
    <layout id="header_layout_2" label="Header Layout 2" type="header" />
    <layout id="header_layout_3" label="Header Layout 3" type="header" />
    <layout id="header_layout_4" label="Header Layout 4" type="header" />
    <layout id="header_layout_5" label="Header Layout 5" type="header" />
</config>
```

I want to **add a sixth layout**. For the moment I have modified this file directly to add a line (layout 6), but I know that this is not correct because the changes I made will disappear the next time I update the code that does not belong to me.

I searched but I don't know if it is possible to override this kind of file. If so, please give me some hints or on the contrary confirm that we can't...

Comment: See that answer it can help you [An response here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/223699/68793)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a child theme, You can override the file by copying the file to below location

> app/design/frontend/YourVendor/Module/CompanyTheme_LayoutSwitcher/layout/layouts.xml

and add a sixth layout or any customization you need

Answer (score 0):

basically, you need to create a child theme, so if any update come then no effect on your theme.

and also use git so you can track the whole summary.