# Override xml files

Tags: magento2, extensions, overrides, cms-block, third-party-module

Is it possible to override etc/import/block.xml with child theme ? 
I have modified block.xml itself and works fine for now but if I update 3rd party extension my modifications will be lost .
 I am trying to override Sm_Bestshop theme. 
How is it possible?

Comment: Check by setting the Module dependencies if it helps! https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend.html

Comment: @Bhaumik1987 Will test it now ! Thanks. Let's see if it works.

Comment: I don't really think It will be possible to override block importing because I must rewrite on already created blocks ...

Comment: Please check this post, if it helps!  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223451/how-to-override-magento-directory-module-etc-xml-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, The best way to change the blocks was to use DataPatch.
overriding must happen with plugin but it's quite complicated